# select the value by which I grouped by when grouping by a function in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery I am trying to group and count activities by their duration in minutes like this:

```sql
SELECT
   TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, MINUTE) AS duration,
   COUNT() AS count
FROM activity
GROUP BY TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, MINUTE)
```

This doesn't compile since `ended_at` and `started_at` are neither grouped nor aggregated.

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: works perfectly for me - just fix `count()` to `count(*)`

Comment: Oh, I also had an `ORDER BY` in the original query which I didn't post in the question because I thought it wasn't relevant. Turns out when I remove it it works. ?!?!

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on my end, and you just need to add a * into COUNT ( ) so your SELECT will be like this:

```
SELECT
      TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, MINUTE) AS duration,
      COUNT(*) AS count
FROM activity
GROUP BY TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, MINUTE)
```